# Fill an array by specific columns in R

Tags: arrays, r, dimensions, populate

This might be a simple question, but I'm new to R and having trouble figuring it out.  I've tried searching extensively for the answer and I cannot come up with it.

I have a dataframe that is 92:24.  I would like to create an array that is (92, 2, 12) which is populated from the columns in the dataframe.  I would like column 1 and 2 to be "stacked", columns 3 and 4, columns 5 and 6, and so on.  The first dimension of the array should correspond to all the odd columns and the second dimension should correspond to all the even columns, with 92 rows and 12 columns in each of the 2 dimensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want the data in this format? Maybe a `tbl_cube` could be useful, but I've never had a reason to use one of those.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/tbl_cube

Comment: Congratulations on getting started with R! I would suggest taking a look at this link so you can see how to make a great reproducible example to help others help you with your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you can do it with `dfarray <- array(as.matrix(df), dim = c(92, 2, 12))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want.
First, create a `data.frame` with the appropriate dimensions.

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:2208, ncol = 24))
```

Then, it's just a columns' shuffle and `dim` trick.

```
mat <- as.matrix(dat)
mat <- mat[, c((1:12)*2 - 1, (1:12)*2)]
dim(mat) <- c(92, 12, 2)

# See the first 5 rows
mat[1:5, , ]
```

Comment: Alternately `evens <- (1:ncol(dat) %% 2) == 0; h <- c(unlist(dat[,!evens]), unlist(dat[,evens])); array(h, dim = c(92, 12, 2))[1:5,,]` but your answer is better.